# Multiple swaps / function / method calls within 1 transaction (Ethereum)

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, web3js, ethers.js

How to initiate multiple swaps (uniswap) within 1 transaction?

I believe it could be possible by passing proper data to uniswap multicall method, but how to create this data and pass the correct format?

Those addresses do such transactions without a separate smart contract. They call uniswap smart contract and pass the appropriate data

Examples:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x792a16cb66e1473d83309231650cdcd62f8e4ff907ee6fb7660166ff87e7e8f4
https://arbiscan.io/tx/0x43645c3dc509fc7a2ded50a1f67760e82716ea5a7bf86c59d74d8db2a157574a (arbitrage)

Answer (score 0):

You can interact with this contract
https://etherscan.io/address/0x5BA1e12693Dc8F9c48aAD8770482f4739bEeD696#code

Here are more details.
https://github.com/joshstevens19/ethereum-multicall

Comment: this one allows to use only view methods. I need the "write" ones

Comment: Did you check the aggregate function of the contract?
There is no function for view multicall in the contract.